# Silverstripe Controller docs confusing

Tags: php, content-management-system, silverstripe

According to docu, "We need to define the URL that this controller can be accessed on. In our case, the TeamsController should be visible at http://yoursite.com/teams/ and the players custom action is at http://yoursite.com/team/players/.". But the controller is defined as

```
<?php

    class TeamController extends Controller {

    private static $allowed_actions = array(
        'players',
        'index'
    );

    public function index(HTTPRequest $request) {
        // ..
    }

    public function players(HTTPRequest $request) {
        print_r($request->allParams());
    }
}

?>
```

Configuration:

```
Name: mysiteroutes
After: framework/routes#coreroutes
---
Director:
  rules:
    'teams//$Action/$ID/$Name': 'TeamController'
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Please don't use closing `?>` tag, it's not needed and might break something (e.g. custom http headers) if you accidently have a space or something else after it, as it'll be outputted directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TLDR;**

Yes, in theory it is correct. Beside a small typo.

**Longer answer**

You want to see the list of players when you access the url *http://yoursite.com/team/players/*. This URL has four parts:

1. the protocol *http://*
2. the domain *yoursite.com*
3. the first part after the domain, */team*
4. the second part after the domain, */player*

Protocol and domain are resolved by your webserver with your SilverStripe installation. Now comes */team*. This should map to your `TeamController` class. Therefor we need to define a *route* so SilverStripe knows, everything starting with *team* should be handled by this controller. We define routes in the yml.config, I prefer a seperate file for routes, e.g. */mysite/_config/routes.yml':

```
Name: mysiteroutes
After: framework/routes#coreroutes
---
Director:
  rules:
    'team//$Action/$ID/$Name': 'TeamController'
```

So any request (after the domain) starting with the word 'team' (note, in your example you had *teams*, that's an important typo that breaks everything) is routed to the `TeamController` class, and the second parameter (in our example "players" is passed as `$Action` parameter. The `TeamController` itself doesn't know of the first part, it just gets the other params named as you defined it in your routes.

This is mapped by `$allowed_actions` in your `TeamController`class:

```
private static $allowed_actions = array(
    'players',
    'index'
);
```

and therefor directly mapped to the `players` method that renders the output.